# ReEx for Google Analytics Goal - match one phrase only if another isnt present

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I have many pages that I am tracking goals on in GA.

I would like to write a regular expression to include `thank-you` but only if the URL doesn't include `email`.

URL examples...

`/thank-you/` *(conversion)*

`/email/thank-you/` *(no conversion)*

`/email/` *(No conversion)*

How can I accomplish this using RegEx? Thank you.

Comment: When `email` is included, is it always followed by `/thank-you` ?

Comment: /email/ does exist as well and should not be counted.

Comment: You could always just run it through 2 patterns

Comment: `if(!Regex.IsMatch(URL, @"/email/") && Regex.IsMatch(URL, @"/thank-you/"))`

Comment: Try `^(?!.*\bemail\b)(?=.*thank-you)`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/ad6c6O/1

Comment: The regex matches URLs that include `thank-you` without `email`. Your demo is using URLs with both. See my demo above.

Comment: Just FYI, GA regex is RE2 based, thus, no lookarounds are supported, no specific methods are available... There are filters that you can set (one with *matches* and another *does not match*) and then either enable or disable.

Comment: Thanks everyone! 

Wiktor, so you're saying the above might not work in GA?

Comment: Have you tried a simple regex: `^\/thank\-you\/$` . Unfortunately regex in GA is limited as it doesn't support lookarounds. This would be the best fit for your case.